# NSPredicate with sub array

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I am looking at the following type of data structure:

```
{
    author = "Author 1";
    channelIds =         (
        7
    );
},
{
    author = "Author 2";
    channelIds =         (
        7,
        1
    );
},
,
{
    author = "Author 3";
    channelIds =         (
        3,
        7
    );
}
```

I'd like to build an array consisting of all items where **channeldIds = 7**.

I was trying things along the lines of the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate * filterById = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"channelIds[0] = '7'"];
```

- How can I do what I'd like here?
- I can have an x number of channelIds, is there any way to iterate in the predicate?

Tia, S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier:

```
NSPredicate *filterById = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"channelIds CONTAINS %@", @"7"];
```

This is assuming that your `channelIds` value is an array of *strings*.  If it's an array of numbers (`NSNumber`), then your format string would simply be `@"channelIds CONTAINS 7"`.