# Using predicates to search nested arrays in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nspredicate, predicate

I have an array of Address Book contact dictionaries, with the dictionary for each name containing a string for the name and an array of email addresses. Here's a snippet of what the NSLog output looks like when I log the array of contacts:

```
{
    emails =         (
        "something@yahoo.com"
    );
    name = "Some Name";
},
{
    emails =         (
        "john.public@gmail.com",
        "john@public.name"
    );
    name = "John Q. Public";
},
[etc.]
```

I want to use a predicate to search these dictionaries by email address, returning any and all entries that have at least one email address that matches the search term.

So far, I have tried the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997720/nspredicate-with-sub-array), just using CONTAINS, like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"emails CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
```

but any search just returned an empty array. If I search the name field instead, like so, it works fine:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
```

So I'm pretty sure it's specifically with searching the array. Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aaand I figured it out. This works:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY emails CONTAINS[c] %@",currentString];
```

Thanks for being my rubber ducky, SO.